# Name file showing NULL on JOIN

Tags: oracle, join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT cust_FNAME,cust_LNAME,m.movie_title,r.requested_date
FROM Rentalqueue r
RIGHT JOIN Movie m ON r.movie_ID = m.movie_ID
LEFT JOIN Customer c ON r.customer_ID = c.customer_ID
WHERE r.customer_ID = 2
GROUP BY cust_FNAME,cust_LNAME,m.movie_title,r.requested_date;
```

The problem is the customer name is showing as NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your query supposed to do?  Do you really want to use any outer joins here?  If so, why?

Comment: Just wanna show customer name in results. customer_ID and movie_id are in Rentalqueue table.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
SELECT Customer.cust_FNAME, Customer.cust_LNAME, Movie.movie_title, Rentalqueue.requested_date
FROM Customer, Rentalqueue, Movie
WHERE Rentalqueue.movie_ID = Movie.movie_ID
AND Rentalqueue.customer_ID = Customer.customer_ID
AND Rentalqueue.customer_ID = 2
ORDER BY Customer.cust_FNAME, Customer.cust_LNAME, Movie.movie_title, Rentalqueue.requested_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the basics: first, test if there is actually a Customer with `customer_id = 2`.

```
SELECT cust_FNAME, cust_LNAME FROM Customer where customer_id = 2;
```

If zero rows are returned or the name is returned as `NULL` values then there is your problem - you either have no rows to join with or the data is correctly showing `NULL` values.

As an aside - You are doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between `RentalQueue` and `Customer` but you seem to be expecting a non-`NULL` return in `Customer` so, if this is always the case, you can replace the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       cust_FNAME,
       cust_LNAME,
       m.movie_title,
       r.requested_date
FROM   Rentalqueue r
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN Movie m
       ON ( r.movie_ID = m.movie_ID )
       INNER JOIN Customer c
       ON ( r.customer_ID = c.customer_ID )
WHERE  r.customer_ID = 2;
```